# Como executar aplicativo no desktop linux remotamente via comando?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Tenho um servidor em um cliente onde utilizo um aplicativo remoto, as vezes algum usuário vai lá e fecha o aplicativo (não sei se sem querer ou o dono, por medo), então não consigo conectar.

O aplicativo inicia automaticamente quando reinicio o servidor, mas não posso ficar reiniciando o servidor em horário de trabalho.

Eu tenho acesso a linha de comando desse servidor via ssh e poderia executar o aplicativo, mas como ele é visual, da erro remotamente pois ele entende que eu quero executa-lo na rede.

Eu estava pensando em criar um cron somente para executar o atalho do aplicativo para que ele abrisse la na tela do servidor, não sei se é a melhor maneira e se é possível.

Em resumo, preciso executar um aplicativo no desktop linux remotamente via ssh (Kubuntu 16.x) remotamente.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há como setar as variáveis de ambiente no destino, de forma que o programa "encontre a tela" - na verdade, é só a variável "DISPLAY", desde que o usuário que você use com o SSH seja  o mesmo que estiver logado no modo gráfico:

```
[usuario@host ~] export DISPLAY=:0
[usuario@host ~] <programa_desejado>
```

Ou na mesma linha:

```
[usuario@host ~] DISPLAY=:0 <programa_desejado>
```

É interessante notar que há décadas o protocolo do X11 usado pelo Linux foi criado para permitir que você execute um programa na máquina remota que mostre a janela  interaja na máquina a partir da qual você chamou.

Se desejar isso, basta se certificar que na configuração SSH do servidor a opção de `X11Forwarding` esteja habilitada (no Fedora o arquivo fica em  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` , se não for o mesmo arquivo no Debian/Ubuntu é parecido - de qualquer forma deve estar habilitado por padrão)

E aí ao conectar com SSH você usa a opção `-Y`:

```
[usuario@hostlocal ~] ssh -Y hostremoto
[usuario@hostremoto ~] <nome_do_programa>
```

e o programa aparece na tela do hostlocal- isso é automático quando se conecta a partir do Linux/outra máquina com Posix e X11.

No Windows, o PuTTY, o cliente de SSH mais popular, tambem suporta essa funcionalidade, mas depende da instalação de um programa que atue localmente como um servidor X11: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-x-forwarding . No Mac também é  necessário um programa para atuar localmente como X11 server.

Com a mudança gradual para Wayland não sei se essas funcionalidades serão mantidas.

Para executar um programa gráfico a partir do CRON, a ideia é a mesma: se o usuário for o mesmo que estiver logado no modo gráfico, basta setar a variável DISPLAY para o valor `:0`  na mesma linha que dispara o aplicativo.  Veja a ajuda do comando `crontab -e` para fazer isso, e ponha a variável DISPLAY antes do comando, como no segundo exemplo acima.

A mesma variável DISPLAY permite que máquinas Unix funcionem com um servidor para vários thin-terminals: você loga num conjunto diferente de montior/teclado/mouse e entra na máquina com um DISPLAY diferente do ":0" (:1, etc....) - uma só máquina parruda permite vários usuários.  Era um setup comum em universidades nos anos 90. Hoje, com o grande poder dos PCs médios, e o grande consumo de memória de uma sessão de desktop típica (por conta dos sites HTML5 abertos em abas nos navegadores), isso dificilmente valeria a pena. Mas poderia funcionar - e poderia dar uma sobrevida, digamos que alguém tenha um lab com vários PCs em bom estado, mas antigos, com cerca de 1/2GB de memória - um PC novo, com CPU parruda e uns 32GB de memória poderia ser o servidor, e os vários PCs antigos ficariam apenas como thin-clients.  Para vídeo/teclado/mouse o setup é bem simples, usando só essas tecnologias cliente/servidor do X11 - para o som sair corretamente em cada thin-client, complica um pouco.

Comment: Aqui funcionou com o primeiro comando export DISPLAY=:0 depois nome_do_programa, muito obrigado